# Notation question - series that diverges slower than $a_n = n$

Tags: calculus, notation

Is there a popular notation for all series $b_n$ so that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{b_n}{n} = 0$

Comment: $o(n)$
Just look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation
There is table defining o(g(n)), if g(n)=n, you have what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

***NOT AN ANSWER : WOULDN'T LET ME COMMENT***

Consider the Big O notation.

And let's say we have some bigger function $a(x) = 2x^9 + 3x^6 + 3x$.

When discussing the behavior of the function $a(x)$ for giant $x$, these terms $3x^6$ and $3x$ become irrelevant.

So what do we do? We get *rid* of them.

That means that it behaves LIKE $x^9$.

That means that there is a constant $M$ such that $|a(x)| \le M|x^9|$.

We have that $a(x)=2x^9+3x^6+3x<2x^9+3x^9+3x^9=8x^9$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Therefore, letting $M=8$ finishes our justification to use the big $O$ notation.

And in general, that $x^9$ could be any function $g(x)$.

Basically, the big O notation is a shorthand to discuss the behavior of the function as the other terms shrink in relevance.

Big O notation is usually used in discussing asymptotes and behavior of function in limits, as $x$ grows arbitrary large.

You do *not* use Big O to evaluate the expression $\displaystyle x+\frac{1}{x^9}$ at $x=500$ (although it barely makes a difference).

Speaking of difference, Big O notation is also used to denote error.

---

Basically a 10 second summary of Wikipedia for anyone who's too lazy.